Why do l have black little glitchy squares
l am a beginner blender 3D artist and l ran into an issue of these little black glitchy cubes showing up when moving my mouse around and l also saw that when rendering this it made that part turn really black as shown on the right but I’m not sure if it is the same issue with the glitch part or something else and l have tried YouTube videos to try to resolve this problem but no luck. I have a project due tomorrow and l really appreciate your help.

Z fighting, most likely anyway.

Thank you so much l didn’t really knew what z fighting was but l searched it up and looked up a video and it got back to normal thank you so much:D
